# WPML Query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have a client who has an issue with WPML and query_posts();

The posts show up in the default language, but not in the Spanish version of the site.

It shows the fallback h2.

[The site](http://www.attorneytonyadderley.com/)

[The Spanish site](http://www.attorneytonyadderley.com/es/)

[image]

[image]

```
<ul class="news">

                         <?php 
    query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => post,
        'posts_per_page' =>2,
        'order' => DESC,
        'suppress_filters' => 0,

    )); 
?>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <li>
                                <div class="ico-holder"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ico-pen.png" width="25" height="27" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <strong class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title()?></a></strong>
                                        <p><?php echo strip_shortcodes(wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 10 )); ?> </p>
                                    <time class="date-time" datetime="<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </li>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
      <h2>
        <?php _e('Nothing Found','text_domain'); ?>
      </h2>
      <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

I've tried adding `'suppress_filters' => 0,` to the array, but that did not remedy the solution.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Have you tried using `WP_Query` and creating your own query? - https://wpml.org/forums/topic/query_posts-returns-pages-in-original-language-instead-of-translated-ones/

Comment: Are the posts actually translated?

Comment: No, but I can't get it to show up at all. Do they have to be translated first? And I have not. I figured it was related specifically to the plugin since the default page displays it properly.

Comment: Thanks user1049961!

It really was that simple. It was the first time using a site with WPML, so I thought the translations were done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create translated versions of the posts. I did not know that it was not already done, my first time using WPML. The plugin adds a language category to the queried posts.